# advice on Linux networking

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

i have an issue with some networking that i would like some assistance with if possible. i have tried a couple of option but cant get this to work.

--setup--
Device 1:

4 port cpe 
running linux
no internet connection via its wan port
4 lan ports supplying dhcp address
ssh listening locally on 17.16.x.x

device 2

laptop running arch linux
eth0 172.16.x.x ip address (from the cpe)
wan1 10.10.x.x ip address ( internet via a home router)

the laptop gets the internet via wan1 and is connected via eth0 to another linux box (device 2) which has no internet and has a dhcp server running supplying eth0 with its 172.16.x.x address.

i am connected via eth0 and ssh to the cpe box and want to provide it with internet via the laptop so i can pull down some files and run some tools. 
my thought was to forward traffic possible via a route from wan1 to eth0 however every variation i try does not work.

i want to check if this is possible and get some advice on how to do it. any feedback would be great

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to share internet connection to your Device 1 via you laptop? If it's true, you must turn on ip_forward on your laptop and setup NAT (MASQUERADE).

Comment: Yea that's what I want to do. Thanks for the pointer I will look into it